# Are my reflectance values of bands in range and what does DRA in GIS 10.1 do to bands?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, remote-sensing

I have done the TOA correction to red and near infrared bands using raster calculator and calculated NDVI from lansat 8 image.

The NDVI range came as : upper range=184 and lower range=(-235).
When I click on the DRA check box it comes in a range of -1 to +1.

So my question is what does DRA do to the bands? Are my corrected reflectance range value correct?

[image: Before Checking on the DRA box I got NDVI range of -245 to +184 but after I checked the DRA check box it comes within range -1 to +1]

Answer (score 2):

Simply typing DRA into Help gets you to a page that explains what it means, which is dynamic range adjustment and what it does.

There is even an official [ESRI blog](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/07/26/image-analysis-window-what-is-dra/) page that points to the appropriate help page.

Comment: This answer should not have been down-voted. It is fair to expect an op to make a minimum effort in researching their question, which certainly includes checking a software's help. This probably should have been a comment but that is subjective at best.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I find it a bit frustrating these sorts of questions as if you type the word of interest into Help it is nearly always THE TOP return in the help file, clearly they have not bothered to research the help file for the very software they are using. If on the other hand they say, looked at the help file, makes no sense to me, blah blah blah then that's an OK question to ask in my opinion as may be someone else can describe it in an easier way. I know I benefit from reading other peoples interpretations about complex ideas.